# Count Total in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am doing a specific training calculation in Excel.

I have 8 different types of training.
For Example:

```
Employee A
Date 1 L - Lobby
Date 2 E - Exterior
Date 7 G - Garage
```

How can I add the total training done for employee A?
The total training for Employee A is 3 but I am using L, E, G in my table instead of a number. I need each letter = 1, so it will give me the total.

Also, can I use the regular =SUM function or should I use the =COUNTA function?
I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question...

Assuming:

- Column A = Employee
- Column B = Date
- Column C = Training Type

you can use `COUNTIF($A:$A, "Employee A")` to count the number of entries for *Employee A* (etc)

If you want to know home many entries of each type, you can use `COUNTIFS($A:$A, "Employee A", $C:$C, "L - Lobby")` etc

If I've misunderstood the question, please clarify the question...

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple sample and use the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=E2)*($C$2:$C$12=F2))
```

[image]